# SAS optimizer in macro language

Tags: optimization, sas

Does anyone have an experience with a SAS optimizer to support fitting of complex, multi-stage (several data steps and procs), non-linear function fitting. This would presumably be written in macro language.

Comment: The question as posted is far too broad for this site. Have a go at implementing something or maybe try http://codereview.stackexchange.com